# How do I display an unordered list in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, animation

I have to display a text field and a button “Generate times table”. When the user enters an integer from 1 to 9 and clicks the button, two duplicate times tables will appear side-by-side. However, the times tables on the right needs to be presented in an unordered list style.

When the user enters another number and click the button, the old times tables disappear and the new times tables will be generated accordingly.

I have managed to display one times tables set, however the second version (unordered list) won't display adjacent to it.

```html
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>

    Enter integer:<input onClick="stopCounterAnimation()" id="number" 
    type="text">
    <button onclick="startCounterAnimation()">Start Animation</button>
    <button onclick="stopCounterAnimation()">Stop Animation</button>
    <br/><br/>
    <span id="counter"></span>

    <script>
    var counter = 0;
    var counterSchedule;
    var input = document.getElementById("number");
    var counterSpan = document.getElementById("counter");

    function startCounterAnimation() {
      counterSchedule = setInterval(showCounter, 1000);
    }

    function showCounter() {
      if (~~input.value) {
          if (counter >= 9)
            counter = 0;
          counter++;
          counterSpan.innerHTML = input.value + " X " + counter + " = " 
    + eval(input.value + " * " + counter);
        }
      }

      function stopCounterAnimation() {
        clearInterval(counterSchedule);
        input.value = "";
        counter = 0;
      }

    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Try `counterSpan.innerHTML += '<br/>' `

Comment: @jmargolisvt no error, just don't know the right code to use

Comment: This code was from your previous question where you wanted the multiplication appear and change after a second. Is there any part of this code you want to reuse? Because you obviously don't need all that setInterval/Timeout stuff to simply print a multiplication table.
Your question never implies a need for those intervals either.

Comment: Also duplicate of [How do I display a list when button is clicked in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57992223/how-do-i-display-an-unordered-list-in-javascript)